# converting const char* to vector<double> better way

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm receiving `const char*` via UDP. The size of this text varies (i.e. not fixed size). This text has values of double type. I want to convert it to `vector<double>`. This what I've done.

```
std::vector<double> convertToDoubVect(const char * buff)
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    std::istringstream data(buff);

    int i = 0, count = 0;

    // get number of doubles in const char* by incrementing count
    while( buff[i] != '\0' )
    {
        if ( buff[i] == ' ')
            ++count;
        ++i;
    }

    // allocate an array for the total doubles
    double *n = new double[count+1];

    // convert const char* to vector<double>
    for ( int i(0); i <= count; ++i)
    {
        data >> n[i];
        vec.push_back(n[i]);
    }

    delete n;

    return vec;
}

int main()
{

    const char *doubStr = "2.3 4.3 5.6 2.1 4.4 3.1";
    std::vector<double> vec = convertToDoubVect(doubStr);

    for ( int i(0); i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is definitely not an elegant way but it did the trick. Any suggestions! I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a code review.  Consider asking for code reviews on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You may replace `double *n` by a simple `double`. no array required.

Comment: @cdhowie, sorry but I'm not asking for reviewing I'm asking for another way to fulfill this task using another function.

Comment: why use double* when you can have std::vector<double>?

Comment: What is the array for? Why not push a double into the vector?

Comment: For the array, yes my bad sorry.

Comment: By the way, although the array is of course completely unnecessary, remember it's `delete` for `new`, and `delete[]` for `new[]`. Your code has undefined behavior as is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const char* doubStr = "2.3 4.3 5.6 2.1 4.4 3.1";
std::istringstream iss(doubStr);
std::istream_iterator<double> it(iss), end;
std::vector<double> v(it, end);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/kD9nqD)

Comment: Thank you for declaring your iterators in a seperate statement. I see so many people doing stuff like this: `std::vector<double> v{std::istream_iterator<double>(iss), std::istream_iterator<double>()};` and I find it horrifying.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment by @cdhowie. Nonetheless, it seems that `double *n = new double[count+1];` is extraneous. Don't bother allocating and later deleting an array here; just use a scalar.

The entire conversion loop could be

```
// convert const char* to vector<double>
for ( int i(0); i <= count; ++i)
{
    double n;
    data >> n;
    vec.push_back(n);
}
```