# C++ How can I take values out of a stringstream and put them into a vector so that I can separately access them?

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I have values in a string stream, separated by spaces, and I want to pull these values out individual and put them into a vector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting const char\* to vector<double> better way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453368/converting-const-char-to-vectordouble-better-way)

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string s( "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" );
std::istringstream is( s );

std::vector<int> v( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


int main() 
{
    std::string s( "1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" );
    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::vector<int> v( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), 
                        std::istream_iterator<int>() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If the vector is already defined then you can write

```
v.assign( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), 
          std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Or your could use some standard algorithm with input iterators using std:;istream_iterator as the input iterator to select some individual values from the stream.